# 415 status on json serialized using Jackson - Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I'm trying to set up a small webservice and I ran into a bit of an issue. I'm using Spring boot on the server side and testing it using a java client.

webservice method code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/user/",consumes="application/json",produces="application/json")
public User getUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    System.out.println("success!");
    return user;
}
```

client code:

```
HttpURLConnection con;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
String spec = "http:/127.0.0.1:8080/user/";
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
String requestMethod = "POST";
try {
        URL url = new URL(spec);
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod(requestMethod);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        System.out.println(json); //first output
        try (OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()) {
                byte[] input = json.getBytes("utf-8");
                os.write(input, 0, input.length);
            }
            int status = 0;
            if((status=con.getResponseCode())<=399) {
                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    String responseLine = null;
                    while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(responseLine.trim());
                    }
                    ....
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(status); //second output
            }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

code of the user class is rather simple, just field declarations and a constructor

here is the output of the code:

```
{"password":"mypassword","profilePic":null,"reputation":0,"userName":"myusername"}
415
```

As you can see, even though the spring boot method accepts "applications/json" and the connection object sends "Content-Type":"application/json" that has been serialized using a Jackson ObjectMapper, the server returns a 415 Unsupported Media Type response code.

Any ideas why?